# Error opening file for read and write in Unix on Ubuntu

Tags: c, unix

I try to open file for reading and write and I get the next error "fd error
: Permission denied"

```
int fd = open("newfile.txt",O_RDWR);
if(fd == -1)
{
    perror("fd error\n");
}
```

*Updates

I added this permission and still, I get the same error

```
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
int fd = open("newfile.txt",O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode);
if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("fd error\n");
    }
```

Comment: Does `newfile.txt` have read and write permissions?

Comment: Or if `newfile.txt` does not initially exist, then do you have write permission on the current working directory?

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to read or write the file? Or on the directory where it's located? Or any of the parent directories in the path?

Comment: You get a better error message with `perror("newfile.txt")`

Comment: Also, to create a new file with [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) you *must* use the `O_CREAT` flag, and provide the protection flags as a third argument.

Comment: Do `ls -ld . newfile.txt` in the directory you are when executing the program. Also do `id` and put the output from both in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the permission and try again. If the fd is -1 it means file is not loaded by OS.